# Chrome not displaying div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, dom

I have a site which uses the Bootstrap framework.
Unfortunately some of the classes of divs do not display in **Chrome** (only) & I can't figure out why.

Bootstrap sits on another PHP framework - I did not create this original code; but I can modify it easily enough.
The hidden divs ***are*** being rendered in the DOM (I can inspect them).
I've searched all references to the hidden div class (`col-ad`) & they all come up as nice & mundane CSS with no obvious things that could make the div hidden. No javascript references either.

If I rename the class (eg. `Xcol-ad`) in the DOM the div displays.

When I inspect the div I get the following:

[image]

Which is the only thing I can find which could be the culprit. Unfortunately I can't find a reference to this within any of my code.

Have tried modifying the DOM (`display:block!important`) without success.

When I click on the `<style>` tags it (I think) points to something called #shadow-root(open) at which point I'm lost. I've searched for info about this but haven't been successful (I'm not 100% sure this is even the problem) - have changed a setting within Chrome (Show user agent shadow DOM) without success.

It feels like my styling has been taken over somewhere & I don't know where.

EDIT: [link to demo site where I got script](http://classified.flippyscripts.com/all-recent-1.html) - just tried looking at site with browsershots tool & ads appear even with Chrome, so may be my version(?)

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: And also a link to the site in question if possible

Comment: I'm not sure what code i can give you - the div is kinda boring `<div class="media col-ad">`, .media isn't referenced much as with .col-ad... this may help [link to demo site](http://classified.flippyscripts.com/all-recent-1.html); on my version of Chrome the ad listings are not displaying. BUT other versions of Chrome they seem ok.

Comment: what's the relevance to php here? since you tagged as php, but no code to support the question.

Comment: i guess no relevance - the site is built with PHP but i'm unsure if it has anything to do with the issue i'm having. I'll remove it in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is clearly some kind of ad blocker extension, that inserts its own style rules to block/hide elements – look at the identifiers used in that selector, should be pretty obvious.

Edit: [further explanation, from comment]

The selector contains “ad” in all imaginable combinations, plus “advertisement”, “banner”, “sponsor” showing up as well. That is a typical kind of “kill ’em all (at least the most obvious ones)” attempt by an ad blocker – and that often leads to collateral damage.

You can also see `.ads_320_100` there, which is targeting a specific, typical banner size; some blockers even remove all images that have that kind of “dimensions” specified in their name, for certain “ad-typical” image sizes. (Even though it makes server-side management of different image sizes easier, I’d recommend to stay away from such naming schemes – for this exact reason.)

Comment: Bang. That was it... AdBlocker. i looked everywhere but in front of my face. Do you mean pretty obvious as in the prevalence of the word "ad" or something else?

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I meant – “ad” in all imaginable combinations, plus “advertisement”, “banner”, “sponsor” showing up as well. That is a typical kind of “kill ’em all (at least the most obvious ones)” attempt by an ad blocker – and that often leads to collateral damage. (You see `.ads_320_100` there – some blocker even remove all images that have that kind of “dimensions” specified in their name, for certain “ad-typical” image sizes. Even though it makes server-side management of different image sizes easier, I’d recommend to stay away from such naming schemes – for this exact reason.)